# flask - throwing custom error on invalid query parameter type

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am building a simple REST API using flask. I have the following definition for the GET method and would like to handle 2 cases, 1) throw a custom error when the query parameter value is not of correct type and 2) Throw error for all other routes(post, update, delete)

```
 def get(self):
            parser.add_argument('a'  )
            parser.add_argument('b', type=int)
            parser.add_argument('c', type = int)
            args = {}
api.add_resource(test, '/test/')

**Expected endpoints**: url/test?a=xxxx&b=yy&c=zz
```

I tried using try exception to throw a custom error when input type is not correct but it didnt work.

Any suggestions how to handle the above cases.